# Ruby on Rails: Why the confirmation message does not appear in "link_to('delete', ...)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, confirmation, link-to

I have the following link next to one of my products:

```
<%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'destroy', :id => product.id}, :class => 'action', :confirm => 'Are you sure?') %>
```

but when I click it, the confirmation box does not appear.

The generated HTML is:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure ?" class="action" href="/products/destroy/48">Delete</a>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to("Delete", product, :method => :delete, :class => 'action', :confirm => 'Are you sure?') %>
```

check your `javascript_include_tag`
and it should work fine :)

Comment: You probably had a typo. I got: `undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x237f678>:0x237d590>`. What did you mean rather than `product` ?

Comment: product is an object that you want to delete

Comment: Could you please explain what's wrong with my `link_to(...)` comparing to yours ?

Comment: yup :) your link_to has no information which controller should do your delete action!

Comment: about link_to -> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: I thought that the convention is to take the controller I'm currently in. Where do you specify the controller in your code ? In the link I see 4 signatures. Which one your code uses ? Is `product` a `url` ? part of the `options` ?

Comment: product is equal to pruduct_path(produckt.id)

Answer (score 1):

try adding it as a data-attribute

> data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }

Answer (score 0):

Ensure rails.js is being loaded on the page. The easiest way to accomplish this is with:

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

Comment: Strange. Are there any Javascript errors in the console on page load?

Comment: Really strange :) Now I get the following error: `undefined method `product_path' for #<#<Class:0x21b9dc0>:0x21ad250>` (I don't know why it didn't appear before that)

Comment: Do you have `resources :products` in your routes file?

Comment: I added `resources :products` to the routes file. Now it fails with `The action 'show' could not be found for ProductsController`. Indeed, I want the application to go to the `list` action after it deletes the product. How do I specify the url it goes to after the link is clicked ?

Comment: If your controller is using the new Rails 3 syntax, something like: `respond_with(@product, :location => products_path)`

Comment: How do I combine `respond_with` and `link_to` ?

Comment: `respond_with` allows the controller to route properly. `link_to` is an HTML-generating helper method. They are do not work together directly.