# Destroy Function in Ruby On Rails does not work (Another thread)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, destroy

before I opened this post I read a lot of post on stackoverflow and I tried the solutions...

from:
[Ruby on Rails: Why the confirmation message does not appear in "link_to('delete', ...)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437991/ruby-on-rails-why-the-confirmation-message-does-not-appear-in-link-todelete?rq=1)

and
[Ruby on Rails: Why the confirmation message does not appear in "link_to('delete', ...)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437991/ruby-on-rails-why-the-confirmation-message-does-not-appear-in-link-todelete?rq=1)

I'm really confused because following the tutorial on the book 
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app

but I have the other version where the toy_app is called demo_app

I don't know if it is a problem of compatibilty but almost every step I do I need to research to solve one configuration error... you know, change sqlite3-ruby for sqlite and so on...

Now I'm on the same problem of others, Destroy Function in Ruby On Rails does not work, I tryed various solution and I can´t make it.

My configuration is:
Windows 7 64 bits
Rails 3.2.19
Ruby 1.9.3

HTML destroy code is:

```
<td><a href="/users/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
```

and my application.html.erb is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DemoApp</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery_ujs' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

application.js looks like

```
 // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And I checked Chrome and Internet Explorer and on both of them Javascript is enabled...

What more can I do??

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any javascript error in the console?

Comment: Hello Christophe yes I have this: Started GET "/assest/jquery_ujs.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-17 08:16:29 -0200
Server asset /jquery_ujs.js - 404 Not Found <3ms>

ActionController::RoutingError <No route matches GET "/assest/jquery_ujs.js" .... and so on....

Comment: Ok, So it means you have an error loading javascript files. That's your error. Do you have jquery packager in your gemfile? If not, you should take a look at this : https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

Comment: Hello Christophe, If I use "Gem list" yes I have "jquery-rails <3.1.2, 1.0.19> and my application.js file looks like 
//
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

Comment: I tryed with //=requier jquery and withouth the // and still not working